# Windows store apps: web request delayed with 1 minute

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

My app needs to perform a lot of diffrerent requests (~ 1-2 per second). I have a type of requests which runs continuously(RequestMade -> ResponseReceived -> RequestMade ->...).

If I enter another screen I should start a new set of requests to run continuously as long as I remain in that screen.

The problem is the that the new set of requests `(the initial request) is delayed with ~ 1 minute`.

Below is posted the code used to perform the requests.

Please note this line is printed out to console at, let's say 12:00:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Writing RequestStream ("+_request.GetType().FullName + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()+")");
```

And the lines:

```
 Debug.WriteLine("Request is posting.....(" + _request.GetType().FullName + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()+")");

 Debug.WriteLine("Reading ResponseStream (" + _request.GetType().FullName + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + ")");
```

are printed at 12:01 (after 1 minute....)

```
private class RequestResponseTask
        {
            private Uri _uri = null;
            private string _uriAddress = null;
            private WebRequest _webRequest = null;
            private ARequest _request = null;
            private JsonTextParser _parser = null;
            private RequestState _requestState = null;

            public RequestResponseTask(ARequest request)
            {
                // uri address
                _uriAddress = CVSCustomRelease.Instance.ReleaseSettings.SelectedPrivateLabel.GetServer(LoginSettings.Instance.SelectedServer).Address
                    + CONTEXTUAL_REQUEST_PATH;
                // uri
                _uri = new Uri(_uriAddress);

                // request
                _request = request;
                _parser = new JsonTextParser();
                _requestState = new RequestState(_request);
            }

            public void StartRequest()
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Starting RUN.......(" + _request.GetType().FullName + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + ")");
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("RUN Started. - for "+_request.GetType().FullName + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
                        _request.ResponseReceived = false;
                        Debug.WriteLine("Before WebRequest ("+_request.GetType().FullName + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()+")");
                            _webRequest = WebRequest.Create(_uri);

                        Debug.WriteLine("after WebRequest (" + _request.GetType().FullName + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + ")");
                        _webRequest.ContentType = "text/x-gwt-rpc;charset=utf-8";
                        _webRequest.Method = "Post";

                        _requestState.Request = _webRequest;

                        // Start the Asynchronous 'BeginGetRequestStream' method call.    
                        Debug.WriteLine("Writing RequestStream ("+_request.GetType().FullName + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()+")");
                        IAsyncResult r = (IAsyncResult)_webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(
                            new AsyncCallback(PostRequest), _requestState);

                        _requestState.ResetEvent.WaitOne();
                        Debug.WriteLine("Reading ResponseStream (" + _request.GetType().FullName + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + ")");

                        IAsyncResult asyncResp = (IAsyncResult)_webRequest.BeginGetResponse(
                            new AsyncCallback(ReadResponse), _requestState);
                    });
            }

            private void PostRequest(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("======================================================");
                Debug.WriteLine("Request is posting.....(" + _request.GetType().FullName + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()+")");

                // End the Asynchronus Request.
                Stream streamResponse = _webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

                ARequest request = _requestState.OriginalRequest;
                request.UpdateTimestampRealtime();
                string postData = request.GetPostData();

                EventsLog.Instance.WriteEvent("Request: " + postData);

                // Create a string that is to be posted to the uri.
                // Convert the string into a byte array. 
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

                EventsLog.Instance.CurrentSession.AddTraficAmount(TraficType.Outgoing, byteArray.Length);

                // Write the data to the stream.
                streamResponse.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
                streamResponse.Flush();
                Debug.WriteLine("Request POSTED.");
                Debug.WriteLine("======================================================");
                _requestState.ResetEvent.Set();
            }

            private async void ReadResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            {
                _requestState = (RequestState)asyncResult.AsyncState;
                WebRequest myWebRequest = _requestState.Request;

                WebResponse response = (WebResponse)myWebRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                string responseString = await streamRead.ReadToEndAsync();

                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
                EventsLog.Instance.CurrentSession.AddTraficAmount(TraficType.Incomming, byteArray.Length);

                // build response object
                JsonObject jsonObject = _parser.Parse(responseString);
                EventsLog.Instance.WriteEvent("Response: " + jsonObject.ToString() + "\nFor Request: " + _requestState.OriginalRequest.RequestId + " | " +_requestState.OriginalRequest.GetType().FullName);

                _requestState.ResetEvent.Reset();

                // notify listeners
                _requestState.OriginalRequest.ResponseReceived = true;
                _requestState.OriginalRequest.NotifyResponseListeners(jsonObject as JsonObjectCollection);
            }
        }
```

performing a request:

```
 new RequestResponseTask(_request).StartRequest();
```

Comment: Look like there may be some throttling going on, either in Windows, either on the server. Consider doing less requests. Your users would be happy too, especially if they run on a battery powered device connected over 3G.

Comment: These requests are mandatory since the users wants to see the updates "live". It's a stock app...

Comment: Ah, a stock app. Are you sure this is not intentional? This may be a long-polling design, where the server is waiting one minute before answering. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling

Comment: No, the request does not even reach the server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: Your code blocks, which leads to a timeout on another thread (that's where the 1 minute comes from) which then leads to unblocking the first thread.

You have things like BeginGetRequestStream and ResetEvent.WaitOne in your code - which shouldn't be needed in a Windows Store code like yours. Try to use WebClient's async methods or HttpClient instead. Use await instead of WaitOne.

Comment: The app consist of 2 components: a .dll (which is portable between Windows Phone and Windows 8) and a GUI component. The requests are in the portable lib so I must research if the HttpCient can be ported..

Comment: BeginGetRequestStream is "guilty" in my case...there the thread is blocked for 1 min

Comment: HttpClient exists for WP8. You need to looad it via Nuget: AFAIK you need to search for "Microsoft HTTP Client".